# XMMatrixMultiply vs using the * operator

Tags: c++, direct3d, matrix-multiplication

What's the difference between multiplying Matrices together versus using the XMMatrixMultiply?

```
XMMATRIX aXb;       aXb =       XMMatrixMultiply( a, b );
XMMATRIX aXb_Xc;    aXb_Xc =    XMMatrixMultiply( aXb, c );
```

versus

```
XMMATRIX delta = a * b * c;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a difference. XMMatrixMultiply is there for people using C instead of C++.